# Allow Guest User in Azure Access to SQL Server (DEV, Read/Write)

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, azure

I'm a bit new to Azure AD.  I have some software development offshored and have already created a guest account in Azure for the developer.  I've create an account in SQL Server (Manually via the following script):

```
CREATE USER guestUser WITH PASSWORD ='guestPassword12#'
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [guestUser]; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [guestUser];
```

This gives access only to the specific db that the developer needs access to.

I've added the devs IP to firewall rules to allow access.

My question is, how do I link devs guest account to the login above?  Moreover, when tried to access via Azure, there is an error that states that

> No license has been assigned

I create a group named "devGuestSqlServer" and am able to assign licenses.  Is this an AD license I need to assign?  If I do need to assign an AD license, how does that affect security?  Its very important I keep this devs access limited to ONLY what the dev needs access to.

Please note while I have much dev experience, cloud/AD administration I have little experience with.

Regards.